# Trigger an email with complete products info after an order has been placed

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We want to trigger an email with order infos in SFMC after customers place an order on our website. How can we approach this?

We are testing with SFMC TriggeredSendDataExtension but the challenge which we have, is with number of products. As customers can order as many products as he/she wants, we are struggling with storing the ordered products info in data extension because we cannot predict how many fields we need to store products info in a data extension.

**Current solution for one product:**

1. Created triggered-send data extension with predefined fields to hold one product infos.

**Challenge:**
How can we store variable number of ordered products in SFMC Data extension?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one field in you data extension, and store the IDs of the commands using a separator : product1|product2|product3 ("|" is the separator here, but you can use "," or even tabs).

Then you can split this string to get the IDs of the ordered items, using the AMPScript function `BuildRowsetFromString`

See [that question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383917/amp-script-lookup-based-on-multiple-ids-on-the-same-data-field/383926#383926) for insights about your use case.

Comment: @forethought, if this answer solves your issue, thanks for ✓ accepting it. Else, feel free to ask for more details.